# Implement Serializable in BaseLanguage Class

Tags: mps

How can I implement Serializable in a class in BaseLanguage?

What I did so far:

- Using MPS 3.3.4
- Create new solution Project
- Add new Model
- Add `module.JDK@project_stub` as Dependency
- Add `jetbrains.mps.baseLanguage` as Used Language
- Add new Class
- Trigger `implements` in editor.
- Trigger AutoComplete

The editor now shows a list of available interfaces from `java.lang` namespace, like `Clonable`, `Comparable` and so on. However, there is no `Serializable`. The same behavior emerges when I try to implement `Serializable` in a Generator.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You perhaps did not import the java.io@java_stub model to your dependencies. Control + M while in the editor will do the job.

Vaclav

Comment: Not sure why I need to include `java.io@java_stub`, while `module.JDK@project_stub` is unused though.

Comment: java.io@java_stub is a model that contains the classes from JDK that are part of the java.io package, while module.JDK@project_stub does not. You can find similar models for all JDK packages grouped in the JDK solution (Control + Alt + Shift + S).